# Sidebar should be closed after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using sidebar in my web page. But it should not be open when I refresh page. Now when I click on refresh it is opened by default. I want it to be closed. When user want to open it, only then it should get open by clicking on sidebar-icon.
Below is my javascript and CSS for sidebar-menu:

Javascript:

```
var toggle = true;

        $(".sidebar-icon").click(function() {                
         if (toggle)
         {
            $(".page-container").addClass("sidebar-collapsed").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
            $("#menu span").css({"position":"absolute"});
          }
        else
        {
            $(".page-container").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
            setTimeout(function() {
            $("#menu span").css({"position":"relative"});
            }, 400);
         }

        toggle = !toggle;
        });
```

CSS:

```
 .sidebar-menu {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:#b52e31;
    color: #aaabae;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(58, 41, 31);
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(58, 41, 31);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(58, 41, 31);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(58, 41, 31);
   z-index: 999;
}
a.sidebar-icon:hover{
    color:#fff;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed {
  transition: all 100ms linear;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .left-content {
   float: left;
   width: 97%;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back {
    transition: all 100ms linear;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .left-content {
  transition: all 100ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
    float: right;
    width:87%;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-menu {
  width: 65px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-menu {
  width: 230px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-icon {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
   margin-right: 0em;
    margin-top: -8px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #252525;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-icon {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .logo {
  padding: 21px 0;
  height: 63px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #logo {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    display: none;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .down {
    display: none;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #logo {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #menu span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 50ms linear;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #menu span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}
```

What changes should I make? Help me out

Comment: toggle the `display` property of the `.sidebar-menu` from `none` to `block`

Comment: Can you please add for sidebar-collapsed and sidebar-collpased-back css class. Read this to create a minimum complete verfiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NirbhayJha Updated Sir

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle so we can see the working example.